# How can I solve these FX Composer errors?

Tags: shader, nvidia, fxcomposer

I installed **FX Composer 2.5**, but I open it there are always 2 Tasks:

> Task Unknown OpenGL profile: vp30.
>   fxcomposer://localhost/internal#FXDeviceEffect_CG2 -1
>
> Error Failed to validate technique: Simple
>   fxcomposer://localhost/internal#FXDeviceEffect_CG2 -1

Then when I try to start some samples downloaded from NVIDIA website they don't run correctly. Some times the material becomes a red ball with only one line.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 2):

You can blame NVIDIA for these errors. OpenGL does not work on laptop computers. They have not updated their driver software so any NVIDIA cards in the 500 or 600 series will not work with OpenGL. I have an Acer Aspire 5750G laptop with an NVIDIA Geoforce GT 630M and I have the exact same problems as you. For now, there is nothing you can do to correct these mistake. It's not your fault, or your laptops fault. It's NVIDIA's fault.

However, you can circumvent this problem by simply switching from OpenGL to Direct3D9 or Direct3D10. On the default layout, it's on the top right corner of the taskbar. If you don't have Direct3D9 or 10, then uninstall and re-install the program with these add-ons. Direct3D9 and 10 programs have 99% similarity to OpenGL, so any programs you made with OpenGL can just be copied and pasted into Direct3D9.